# Limit size of an ObservableList

Tags: java, list, javafx, observablelist

I'm forced to use an `ObservableList` in a **JavaFx** Application, and my `List` must contains a maximum of 1000 items.

So I was thinking of using a **FIFO system**, but I only see this solution :

```
observableListData.add(...) //1001 item 
if (observableListData.size()>1000){
   observableListData.remove(0); // 1000 item
}
```

I add a lot of items in this list, so I don't think this is the best way to limit the size of my `ObservableList`, is there **another way to do it** ?

EDIT :

To answer some of your question :

- I need an `ObservableList` because it's link to a `ListView`.
- I must use FIFO because I display items of this list

Comment: have you consider own implementation of ObservableList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend [`ModifiableObservableListBase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html), which is the base for collection, returned by `FXCollections.observableList`, in such a way:

```
public class ObservableLimitedList<T> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<T> {
    private LinkedList<T> list;
    private int maxSize;

    public ObservableLimitedList(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        list = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T element) {
        boolean result = super.add(element);
        if (size() > maxSize) {
            remove(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // delegate overrides:

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, T element) {
        list.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected T doSet(int index, T element) {
        return list.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected T doRemove(int index) {
        return list.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Here's the test for this implementation: https://ideone.com/MMhnS6

Comment: Oops, guys, wait before upvoting this. Unfortunately, `observableList` uses `listIterator`, not `add` directly, so one should override it, I should add this to the answer.

Comment: Actually, I would completely rewrite this answer since there's more sensible solution.

Comment: Do this will have an impact on CPU use ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil not really, the additional layer have its cost, but it's not that slow. `ObservableList` itself is not designed for maximal performance. Although, the number of layers is the same as in `FXCollections` methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell the ObservableList itself to limit the size of it.

Here is the link to details of the class and all methodes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html

Can you please tell us what are you trying to make, and why do you need to limit the size? And maybe someone will tell you the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about sub classing it and overriding the add method. Use your if statement inside the overridden method.

Comment: I coul do something like that indeed, but how could I know the code inside the add() method ?